# django template timeuntil timezone

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am rendering some meetings with django templates.

```
{% for meeting in m %}
  <td>{{ meeting.start|date:"j F Y, g:i A" }}</td>
  <td>{{ meeting.start|timeuntil }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

and view code

```
    now = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=-5)
    m = Meeting.objects.filter(
        start__gte=now, status=Meeting.PENDING
    ).order_by("-start")
    context = {
        "m": m,
    }
    return render(request, "meetings/home.html", context)
```

produces a table like

```
Time Requested              Time Pending (hrs)
7 December 2019, 12:00 AM   2 days
5 December 2019, 12:00 AM   12 minutes
4 December 2019, 11:00 PM   0 minutes
```

my browser is in EST time and the api is UTC. The start time is rendered in local time correctly. But the `timeuntil` countdown is not in the localtime. Is there a good way to achieve the desired output?

So far the best thing I can think of is to compute another datetime column with the client's timezone difference applied. Then the template could simply render `{{ meeting.start_local|timeuntil }}`.

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution is to compute a field `start_local`, `timeuntil` can render in utc time

```
# views.py
...
    client_offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=-5)
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now() + client_offset
    m = Meeting.objects.filter(
        start__gte=start_time, status=Meeting.PENDING
    ).order_by("-start")
    for meeting in m:
        meeting.start_local = meeting.start - client_offset
    context = {
        "m": m,
    }
    return render(request, "meetings/home.html", context)
```

template

```
{% for meeting in m %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ expert.start|date:"j F Y, g:i A" }}</td>
    <td>{{ expert.start_local|timeuntil }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```